How to get an OutputStream to store in an array list which can then be iterated
So I have a code which runs powershell scripts, I had it return me the name and the starttime of the currently running processes. What I want is for this output to be stored in an array list because I want to be able to iterate through the names and start times of these applications.
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //Getting the version
        String command = "Get-wmiobject -Class win32_Product";
        // Executing the command
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powershell -command \"Get-Process | select name, starttime\"");
        // Getting the results
        p.getOutputStream();

        String line;
        System.out.println("Standard Output:");
        BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        stdout.close();
        System.out.println("Standard Error:");
        BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getErrorStream()));
        while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        stderr.close();
        System.out.println("Done");

    }

   }


This is the code, and here I want to store the output (p.getOutputStream) in an arraylist so then I can iterate through it. I did have a look at the similar questions but couldn't solve it

What should the List contain? All lines? If so, you might want to check BufferedReader#lines.

Instead of System.out.println(line); do yourArrayListOfStrings.add(line);. Or do both if you want both. That’s basically it.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be more precise with the expected result of your operation. As @dan1st says, you haven’t told us whether you want the ArrayList to contain the chars, the lines, the two output streams or the complete output on each stream or what.

If you are using Java 9 or later, maybe the Process API is more appropriate than running a PowerShell command.

Much better to have a strongly typed collection of say (at least) List<record>, where the fields are of types String and Instant. Also, use ProcessBuilder. More powerful and flexible. Abra's idea is better still

The WMI commands are not available in PowerShell Core (6.x+). Better to use CIM commands. Be better prepared by changing Get-WmiObject to Get-CimInstance.
